# Loop UNION ALL by year in MYSQL Select Statement

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a huge table that I want to load in parts, by year, because I think it takes less time to load in my BI tool.

```
SELECT pk, year from Table2
where year='2020'
UNION ALL
SELECT pk, year from Table2
where year='2021';
```

but I want to be able to do a loop like

```
SELECT pk from (
For i> min(Table2.year)
select pk, year from Table2

where year='i'

UNION ALL
i=i+1
next i;) as Query;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Note that I want it by year and a concatenation for pks from the same Table2.